# Защита от f5 в java

Tags: защита

Подскажите, как в java приложении реализовать защиту от f5? Можно ли это делать не в сервлете,  а просто прописывать в jsp странице? Спасибо. Пример через роутер:

~private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Optional commandOptional = ActionFactory.defineCommand(request.getParameter("command"));

```
    if (commandOptional.isPresent()) {
        Command command = commandOptional.get();
        logger.log(Level.DEBUG, command);

        Router router = command.execute(request);
        if (router != null) {
            if (router.getType().equals(RouteType.FORWARD)) {
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(router.getPagePath());
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + router.getPagePath());
            }
        } else {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("nullPage", "Page not found");
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + PathForJsp.ERROR.getPath());//LOGIN
        }
    }~
```

Comment: Никак, пользователь может делать со своим браузером всё что пожелает

Comment: Всмысле от нажатия F5 на компе клиента? Тогда никак, можно определить что F5 нажата, и клиент повторно делает запрос на страницу - да можно, допустим используя билет и куки.

Comment: *Можно ли это делать не в сервлете* - а как вы делаете это на сервлете? Опубликуйте для примера... тогда думаю... подскажут можно ли такое записать прямо на jsp. Я и сейчас считаю что на сервлете такое напрямую сделать нельзя.

Comment: Пример через роутер выше

Comment: Решение вопроса:  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get   . Только не пойму,как это реализовать